# How do I skip over a decimal separator in a string?

Tags: swift, string, deprecated

I'm getting a warning that `scanDecimal()` was deprecated in iOS 13.0 but I can't find anything that suggests what should be used instead.

In this function, `scanner.scanDecimal(nil)` is used to simply scan past an NSDecimal representation by returning true.

I've looked through Apple's (cough) documentation and there's no alternative that I can see there. Does anyone know the new way of doing this?

```
extension String {
  // Returns true if the string represents a proper numeric value.
  // This method uses the device's current locale setting to determine
  // which decimal separator it will accept.

  func isNumeric() -> Bool {
    let scanner = Scanner(string: self)
    
    // A newly-created scanner has no locale by default.
    // We'll set our scanner's locale to the user's locale
    // so that it recognizes the decimal separator that
    // the user expects (for example, in North America,
    // "." is the decimal separator, while in many parts
    // of Europe, "," is used).

    scanner.locale = Locale.current
    
    return scanner.scanDecimal(nil) && scanner.isAtEnd
   }
}
```

Comment: Can’t you use a NumberFormatter for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a non-deprecated [`scanDecimal`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/scanner/3200282-scandecimal) method that doesn't take a parameter and returns a `Decimal?` instead of a `Bool`. You can use the return value of this method to determine if the scan was successful or not. If the return value is nil, the scanner failed to scan a `Decimal`. If not nil, the scan was successful.

```swift
return scanner.scanDecimal() != nil && scanner.isAtEnd
```